# Paste in place leave gaps in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using Photoshop CS6.

As I make a selection and cut it (copy and delete) I would then like to paste it in the exact same position but on another layer. As I use the "paste in same position" command, a little gap is left.

This ALWAYS happened since I use Photoshop (CS4, CS5 or CS6).

How can I prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve by doing that? -- You are cutting a part of an image and pasting it in the same place. The way I see it, leaving the document as it is would do a better job. What if you just copy and paste without the part where you delete the contents of your selection?

Comment: oh! that is a good idea and it works fine, thanks! I just want to change the face of the person, but keep the hair in front of the new faces I'm going to paste. Not a PS pro here... I just like to use it to make fun of my friends. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to anti-aliasing on non-perpendicular edges. Anti-aliasing is the processes designed to make odd edges appear a bit smoother without being "stair-stepped" and jagged.

In order to create an angle or curve along a pixel grid, Photoshop must choose which pixels to grab and which to ignore. In some cases, and based upon selection settings, Photoshop may grab a pixel at a lower opacity in order to create the visual appearance of a soft or smooth edge.

The thin white line you are seeing is a result of having a white background behind the anti-aliased edges. If you were to paint a dark color behind the pasted layer, or change the documents background color to a dark color, you would not notice the white edge as much if at all.

Another way to remove that white edge would be to duplicate the pasted layer several times. This will stack the partially transparent pixels until they appear solid. However, this will make those odd-angle edges appear more jagged.

Using layer masks rather than cutting and pasting would also assist in lessening the anti-alias edges.

In the end, it often requires some care to create edges which blend smoothly. High quality work is rarely as simply as copy and paste. It's generally copy, paste, blend a bit.

Comment: Another alternative is not to cut the pixels, but sumply to copy them. Then the area where they were won't be filled with white. Instead, it will just be filled with the original pixels.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Hi there! You might want to add that as a new answer, it might be short but it's valid as one :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of anti-aliasing.  When you look at the selection tool's controls, you will notice an anti-alias checkbox.  Uncheck it and redo your selection.  It will ensure that no blending is used on edge pixels and will not produce the line though it will have a slightly more "jagged" feel in images with lower pixel counts.

Comment: this is the closest, but still not there :(

Comment: My anti-alias checkbox is unchecked (and disabled / grayed out). So that's not the cause of the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way - when you have your selection, right click inside of it and choose Cut via Layer and that will cut the selection and place it on a new layer exactly where it was on the original layer. It is always perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mac Photoshop CS 6 here. My solution (credits to @deecemobile for this):

- with area to cut already select
- Layer > New > Layer via Cut

or with keyboard shortcut

Shift + Cmd + J